# Looking for a PDF of the British Chess Magazine, Sep. 1907

Tags: history

I am looking for a PDF copy of British Chess Magazine dated September 1907 which contains an analysis of a game between Neustadtl and Porges.

Comment: It's been a while but I accidentally stumbled on your question. if you still need it let me know, I have a copy.

Comment: Thank you. I found a copy. By the way it turns out to be a draw despite what various chess publications have stated. Grand Master Karsten Muller has confirmed this.

Answer (score 4):

First place to go is the Chess Archaeology web site, in particular the subsection
"Library" (URL: http://www.chessarch.com/library/library.shtml)

(You'll find two scans: one from Princeton, another from Stanford.)

Another useful source is the WorldCat library (URL: https://www.worldcat.org/). While it does list printed copies as well as copies on microform or in digital form, you can easily search only for digital copies (usually listed as eBooks, eMagazines or eJournals)

In this particular case, however, there seems to be no e-copies listed.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are very unlikely to find a legal copy online for copyright reasons. However, according to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/leedslibraries/status/1333773052052709379), Leeds Libraries have hard copy going all the way back to 1892.

> Our collections are full of historic and current chess books and
> magazines, like the British Chess Magazine going all the way back to
> 1892! So if you want to become a Master, the library is the place to
> start.

Perhaps it's worth your while to get in touch with them, particularly if you live in the UK.

Comment: Far from an expert here, but under English Law doesn't copyright expire 70 years after the author's death? https://www.gov.uk/copyright/how-long-copyright-lasts If so it's quite likely copyright is not a problem here

Comment: @IanBush The magazine hasn't died and I expect they hold copyright to the contents of their magazines.